# c++ Write Chars into Batch file

Tags: c++

Why does this give error at '%' as incorrect formatted speical character.

```
ofstream batch;
batch.open("C:\tesfile.bat", ios::out);
batch << "@echo off\n";
batch << "set Dir=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\ \n";
```

Also i gave c:\ to create bat file it creates bat file at the app folder (where the app is placed).

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You should either escape special character `\` in your string, or use C++11 raw literals (much better option in my view!) like this:

```
batch.open(R"(C:\tesfile.bat)", ios::out);
```

Comment: @RPGillespie, noticed that and fixed :) But thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

In a string, you need to escape your backslashes (`\`) as `\\`. Otherwise, the compiler thinks you are trying to insert special characters like `\n`:

```
batch.open("C:\\tesfile.bat", ios::out);
batch << "@echo off\n";
batch << "set Dir=C:\\Users\\%USERNAME%\\AppData\\ \n";
```

As a thought exercise, imagine what would happen if you didn't escape your backslashes:

```
batch.open("C:\nifty_folder", ios::out); //\n in "nifty" causes a newline!
```

In fact, your original code has an unintended consequence!

```
batch.open("C:\tesfile.bat", ios::out); //\t is a tab!
```